# Using dictionary for displaying number frequency?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple macro that uses a dictionary in order to create a mapping of numbers in a range. I have it map unique values and I can see how it's creating a tally of frequency of occurrence, but I don't know how I'd transfer this working memory onto a sheet? I would just like these unique values printed with maybe the frequency of occurrence next to them.

```
Sub Frequency()

Dim dict As Object
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set rng = Range("A1:D7")

For Each cl In rng.Cells
    dict(cl.Value) = dict(cl.Value) + 1
Next

'here is where I'd want it to paste into a new sheet so I can apply conditional formatting

End Sub
```

Comment: Here's a [link](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Reading_through_the_Dictionary) I've found to be quite helpful with dictionary related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the few lines at the bottom here

```
Sub Frequency()

Dim dict As Object
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set rng = Range("A1:D7")

For Each cl In rng.Cells
    dict(cl.Value) = dict(cl.Value) + 1
Next

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets.Add

ws.Range("A1").Resize(dict.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
ws.Range("B1").Resize(dict.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict.items)

End Sub
```